# Possible to make a software based receiver for wireless Keybord´s and mouse´s?

Tags: bluetooth, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard

Is there a possibility to make wireless mouse's and keyboard's useable again without the receiver dongle?

In most cases I saw it is just a Bluetooth receiver, so my assumption is that if my PC has Bluetooth already I only need a kind of software.
And in cases when WiFi 2,4GHz is used, I could use my WiFi card, or am I wrong?

Is it, if my assumptions are wrong, possible to use a esp32 or asp8266 instead of the dongle?
If there is a possibility to use the hardware although the dongle is missed, that would avoid a lot of trash.

Comment: Can you purchase a replacement dongle from the manufacturer?

Comment: hey, i am looking for a more diy like sollution, and i dont think that they have replacement dongle caused by the age of the hardware...

Comment: In that case you should look at the Stack Exchange Electrical Engineering board.

Comment: No, not all radios are Bluetooth (WiFi is not Bluetooth, for example, an neither are the proprietary dongle although all may use the same frequency bands). Any wireless peripheral not specified as Bluetooth isn't Bluetooth. Your hardware either requires a very specific dongle or, much rarer, it may work with similar ones from the same manufacturer. Same Logitech models can work with a "unified" T/R device. So no, it CAN'T be done.

Comment: See the Logitech mouse site, for example: https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/mice.html . Some use Bluetooth, some use other protocols. Note that some devices can be paired with the dongle of another device, so you might be able to use the mouse along with a wireless keyboard's dongle... or not.